# Java: Adding the same object in a NavigableSet rejected

Tags: java, set

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class AnotherBackedCollectionsTest{

    public static void main(String... args){

        Shape square = new Shape("square");
        Shape circle = new Shape("circle");
        Shape triangle = new Shape("triangle");

        NavigableSet<Shape> shapes = new TreeSet<Shape>();
        shapes.add(square);
        shapes.add(circle);
        shapes.add(triangle);

        System.out.println("New shape added? " +shapes.add(new Shape("square")));

        for(Shape s : shapes){
            System.out.println(s.getName());
        }


        Set<Shape> shapes2 = new HashSet<Shape>();
        shapes2.add(square);
        shapes2.add(triangle);
        shapes2.add(circle);

        System.out.println("New shape added? " +shapes2.add(new Shape("square")));

        for(Shape s : shapes2){
            System.out.println(s.getName());
        }
        
    }
}
```

```java
class Shape implements Comparable<Shape>{

    private String name;

    public Shape(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Shape shape){
        return this.name.compareTo(shape.getName());
    }

}
```

And I get this output:

```
New shape added? false
circle
square
triangle
New shape added? true
triangle
square
square
circle
```

As you can see, I did not override the `equals()` method on the `Shape` object. What I found weird here was when I tried to add another `Shape` object with the name "square" in the `NavigableSet`, it rejected it somehow. Is is because `Shape implements Comparable<T>` so it used the overriden `compareTo()` method to determine method equality?

Basically, what I'm trying to ask is how did the NavigableSet determine that I was trying to add a duplicate object where, in fact, I did not override the equals() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) doesn't use `equals()` to compare elements. It uses the `Comparable` interface.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

As the documentation also notes, if you expect your set to obey the general `Set` contract, your must define `equals()` in a manner that's consistent with `compareTo()`:

> The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

On the other hand, `HashSet` does use `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and pays no attention to `compareTo()`.

This explains the difference in behaviour.

In a nutshell, to make your elements as widely compatible as possible, make sure to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Perhaps the question was quickly edited. For `HashSet` both `equals` and `hashCode` are needed. Should be consistent with `compareTo`. I believe you can get **weird** behaviour with `HashSet` in Oracle Java SE 8.